# Execute Unix system command from JAVA problem

Tags: java, macos, system-information

I am facing a weird issue with executing a system command from JAVA code.
Actually i want to get the `Mac OSX` system information from my JAVA App.
For that im using

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("system_profiler -detailLevel full");`

This is working fine.If i print the output,it is cool.
But i want to write this information to a `plist` file for future use.For that im using the -xml argument of `system_profiler`.like,

```
 String cmd = "system_profiler -detailLevel full -xml > "+System.getProperty( "user.home" )+"/sysinfo.plist";
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Basically this should create a plist file in the current users home directory.

But this seems to be not writing anything to file.

Am i missing something here ?

Comment: Can you double check if user.home system property is set?

Comment: yes,it is set.also i have tried creating a shell script in the home and calling that script from JAVA,it is working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My Java is more than rusty, so please be gentle. ;-)

1. `Runtime.exec()` does not automatically use the shell to execute the command you passed, so the IO redirection is not doing anything.
2. If you just use:

   ```
   "/bin/sh -c system_profiler -detailLevel full > path/file.plist"
   ```

   Then the string will be tokenized into:

   ```
   { "/bin/sh", "-c", "system_profiler", "-detailLevel", "full", ">", "path/file.plist" }
   ```

   Which also wouldn't work, because `-c` only expects a single argument.

Try this instead:

```
String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "system_profiler -detailLevel full > path/file.plist" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd);
```

Of course, you could also just read the output of your `Process` instance using `Process.getInputStream()` and write that into the file you want; thus skip the shell, IO redirection, etc. altogether.

Comment: Excellent,Working like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Christian.K is absolutely correct.  Here is a complete example:

```
public class Hello {

  static public void main (String[] args) {
    try {
      String[] cmds = {
        "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -l *.java | tee tmp.out"};
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec (cmds);
      p.waitFor ();
      System.out.println ("Done.");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println ("Err: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

If you weren't using a pipe (`|`) or redirect (`>`), then you'd be OK with `String cmd = "ls -l *.java"`, as in your original command.

If you actually wanted to *see* any of the output in your Java console window, then you'd ALSO need to call `Process.getInputStream()`.

Here's a good link:
[Running system commands in Java applications](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016)