# Executing ANT command programmatically from Java throws up error

Tags: java, ant

Executing Ant command from Java throws up error

Tried below steps but could not succeed, any help greatly appreciated:

1. We have java based tool in the project built with ant
2. Manually we will run the tool by navigating to the java project and run the tool commands as below:

   1. `cd /Users/Project`
   2. `ant` command

Manually above command runs fine, but when we try the same to execute from Java code:

```
String[] cmd = { "ant run.loader -Dchangeuser=999-Dt=1-Dsl=0-Dpath=PathofInputFile/FileName.txt | tee log.txt", "-c", "//Users//ProjDir" };        
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Above Java code generated error as follows :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ant -v": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
```

Please Note, we have configured Ant path in the PATH variable.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`ant` is a batch/shell script:

- For Windows see: [Run batch script from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/616014/6505250)
- For Linux see: [Run shell script from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526287/6505250)
- For macOS see: [Run Unix system command from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7200372/6505250)

Due Ant is a Java application, it is preferable **[to run Ant by the *ant-launcher.jar*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6733831/6505250)**.

Comment: We have to run ant command from iOS/mac, any suggestions please

Comment: I have extended the answer for macOS. I recommend the platform-independent solution via *ant-launcher.jar*.